# Removing "420x220" placeholder from homepage

Tags: ckan

CKAN's homepage has a placeholder picture "420 x 220". How can I change it or remove it?

I can edit the welcome area text in /ckan-admin but there is no option to manipulate this picture.

[image: example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the image by changing the src value of img tag in ckan/templates/home/snippets/promoted.html

`<img class="img-responsive" src="{{ h.url_for_static('/base/images/placeholder-420x220.png') }}" alt="Placeholder" width="420" height="220" />`